# How to find out the minimum JRE requirement for my Java program

Tags: java, version

I finished a game in Java and sent it to a friend.

Launching the program in my computer worked just fine.

But he got this error:

```
"Could not find the main class: Main. program will exit"
```

My JRE version is the most updated one. His JRE was version 1.6.

He updated his JRE, and the problem was solved.

This is a bit worrying for me, because as far as I know, 1.6 isn't a very old version of the JRE. It's not the most recent one, but not that old.

This is worrying because I'm planning on sending my game to a lot of friends, and trying to distribute it on the internet.

A lot of people don't have the most updated JRE. And they are mostly non-programmers, so I can't expect them to update to the newest version of Java upon downloading my game. They might not know what Java is, even though they got it on their computer, and upon receiving an error, they'll just give up on the game.

If my game wouldn't work with a significantly old JRE, that would be reasonable. It's part of the nature of working with Java. But the fact that a relatively updated JRE, 1.6, doesn't work with my game, is worrying.

Please note: My game isn't implementing anything "special". Swing and KeyBindings are the 'newest' additions to Java that I can think of inside my game)

In short, I'd like to know that my game works on most of the computers it tries to run on. Knowing that it doesn't work on a relatively new JRE, is worrying.

So I have two questions:

1. Is it normal, for a Java program, to have such `"high"`** demands for
   the `JRE version`? Do a lot of Java games demand at least version 1.6
   of the JRE? Is this common?
2. How can I find out the minimum JRE version requirement for my
   program? Is there a methodical way to do this, or do I just have to
   go through all the libraries I use in my game and figure out what's
   the JRE release version for each one?

Comment: Try to run it with other JRE's below 1.6

Comment: First and foremost, you must set up your own development environment to use the minimum JDK you are interested in supporting. This goes both for the source code level and for the produced .class file version.

Comment: Java 6 is 8 years old and was end of life'd almost a year ago.  I wouldn't consider Java 6 to be "relatively new" given it pre-dates a large percentage of Java developers.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the chances are that your friend just didn't have JRE installed and configured correctly. At least the exception points on that.

In general if we put aside the issue your friend has encountered and try to answer your direct question - the best way I believe is to review your program, try to run with jre 1.5, jre 1.6 and 1.7
Of course in general case you should compile your game with the Java compiler that corresponds to the oldest version of JRE that you're planning to be supported. You can download all these JREs/JDKs from Oracle's site

Remember that if you compile on your PC with, say JDK 1.7, than it won't run on JRE 6 later.
The opposite direction should work because Java is backward compatible. Of course you better do you checks anyway.

If you distribute your program as an applet, than I believe this is the best your can do, there is no silver bullet solution here.

If you distribute your game as a "standalone application" you might want to consider "packaging the JRE with the installation pack. In this case the game will "contain" a JRE and a script that will configure everything and run your program with the "bundled" JRE.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "Remember that if you compile on your PC with, say JDK 1.7, than it won't run on JRE 6 later." This isn't true, you can set the produced bytecode version with the target switch.

Comment: OP's error output clearly indicates that a `java` runtime was started and failed to find the `Main` class.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Let me see if I understand everything you said: 1- If I have JDK 1.7 on my computer, while programming my application, than in general it shouldn't be able to run on a JRE older than JRE 7. If I want my application to be able to run on JRE 6, than I need to program with JDK 1.6. Is this correct? 2- There is an option to "package the JRE with the game". In this case, if the game runs and the JRE is too old, than the computer will update the JRE. Is this correct?
If all of this is correct, than I got some questions. Thanks

Comment: 1. Yes its true. One disclaimer - as Kayaman noted its still possible to compile with jre 1.7 with "target" 1.6 (this is an emulation of jre 1.6 instructions set). I answered "in general". 2. No this is not true, this JRE is not really "installed", so it completely depends on you whether to update JRE or leave it as is (usually JRE can be updated with a newer version of the game).